# FileStream behaves differently on Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core

(DotNet Core 2.1) I am using FileStream to write bytes to a file. Developing on Windows and Targeting Yocto Linux on a ARM 32 Bit processor.

When running on Windows I get the correct resulting file.
Same code running on Linux, produces an incorrect file.

Putting both files on the Linux system and checking them with the "file" command yields different results:

```
$ file pc.iso  # <-- GOOD
pc.iso: data

$ file linux.iso # <-- BAD
linux.iso: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", 
sectors/cluster 64, reserved sectors 64, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track
63, heads 255, sectors 100000000 (volumes > 32 MB), FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT
12224, reserved 0x1, serial number 0x53ab8ba2, unlabeled
```

Sample of the code:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.WriteThrough ))
{
    stream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        var bytes = GetBytes(i);
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Why would something like this produce different results on Linux? And/or how can I prevent it from somehow producing a FAT32 image?

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a [mcve]?

Comment: Also, since you're opening an existing file and writing to it, could it be that you started with different files that were good/bad to begin with, unrelated to the changes you're writing to it?